# Short TV film where aliens abduct a family and make them sex-obsessed?

Tags: story-identification, tv, sexuality, alien-abduction

I've been trying to identify a short film that I believe aired on the *Space Channel* probably 5-10 years ago (but I could be wrong about the date and time). It was kind of like something you'd expect to see on *The Outer Limits*, only more comedic.

I don't remember the beginning, but in the film the father inexplicably experiences a super-charged libido. It gets him into trouble at work when he ends up staring at a woman's breasts. The woman complained to the boss who said if he did it again the woman would have his job.

Somehow the man discovers that he and his family were actually abducted by aliens, and he rushes to tell his daughter. When he unexpectedly bursts through the door of his teenage daughter's bedroom,

> he almost doesn't take notice that she is making out with a female friend.

(The implication is that she was not altered by the aliens, but she agrees the crazy alien theory to get her father to go away).

In the very final scene, the man is back at work in a meeting with the woman, who is now wearing her shirt low-cut.

> Nervous and in a sweat, he tries to keep his cool by constantly staring down at a photograph his wife gave him of herself in a sexy pose.

Comment: Can't name the story, though I can well believe it's an episode of "Perversions Of Science" an anthology series of racy and sometimes very clever SF stories.

Comment: That doesn't sound like _Taken_ by Steven Spielberg and yet it does as well maybe?